# Custom fields while loop

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have this code in one of my php files to output every custom field in my wordpress site, now .. I want to limit this code and only target a single custom field by a name of the field. How would I go about that?

```
<?php
 $custom_fields = get_option( 'wp_estate_custom_fields', true);    

 $i=0;
 if( !empty($custom_fields)){  
    while($i< count($custom_fields) ){
        $name               =   $custom_fields[$i][0];
        $label              =   $custom_fields[$i][1];
        $type               =   $custom_fields[$i][2];
        $order              =   $custom_fields[$i][3];
        $dropdown_values    =   $custom_fields[$i][4];
        $slug               =   str_replace(' ','_',$name);

        $slug         =   wpestate_limit45(sanitize_title( $name ));
        $slug         =   sanitize_key($slug);
        $post_id      =     $post->ID;
        $show         =     1;  
        $i++;

        if (function_exists('icl_translate') ){
            $label     =   icl_translate('wpestate','wp_estate_property_custom_front_'.$label, $label ) ;
        }   

        if($i%2!=0){
            print '<p class="half_form half_form_last">';
        }else{
            print '<p class="half_form">';
        }
        $value=$custom_fields_array[$slug];
        wpestate_show_custom_field($show,$slug,$name,$label,$type,$order,$dropdown_values,$post_id,$value);


   }
}

?>
```

Heres the database value of the custom fields entry.

```
a:11:{i:0;a:5:{i:0;s:12:"plochacelkem";i:1;s:44:"[:cs]Zastavěná plocha[:en]Built up area[:]";i:2;s:10:"short text";i:3;s:1:"1";i:4;s:0:"";}i:1;a:5:{i:0;s:12:"plochauzitek";i:1;s:41:"[:cs]Užitková plocha[:en]Usable area[:]";i:2;s:10:"short text";i:3;s:1:"2";i:4;s:0:"";}i:2;a:5:{i:0;s:9:"dispozice";i:1;s:34:"[:cs]Dispozice[:en]Dispositions[:]";i:2;s:10:"short text";i:3;s:1:"3";i:4;s:0:"";}i:3;a:5:{i:0;s:4:"stav";i:1;s:39:"[:cs]Stav Objektu[:en]Property state[:]";i:2;s:8:"dropdown";i:3;s:1:"4";i:4;s:304:"[:cs]Velmi Dobrý[:en]Very Good[:],[:cs]Dobrý[:en]Good[:],[:cs]Špatný[:en]Bad[:],[:cs]Ve Výstavbě[:en]Being built[:],[:cs]Novostavba[:en]Newly built[:],[:cs]K Demolici[:en]For demolition[:],[:cs]Před Rekonstrukcí[:en]Before reconstruction[:],[:cs]Po Rekonstrukci[:en]Reconstructed[:]";}i:4;a:5:{i:0;s:13:"property date";i:1;s:12:"Dostupné od";i:2;s:10:"short text";i:3;s:1:"5";i:4;s:0:"";}i:5;a:5:{i:0;s:17:"property basement";i:1;s:5:"Sklep";i:2;s:10:"short text";i:3;s:1:"6";i:4;s:0:"";}i:6;a:5:{i:0;s:30:"property external construction";i:1;s:10:"Konstrukce";i:2;s:10:"short text";i:3;s:1:"7";i:4;s:0:"";}i:7;a:5:{i:0;s:16:"property roofing";i:1;s:11:"Střešení";i:2;s:10:"short text";i:3;s:1:"8";i:4;s:0:"";}i:8;a:5:{i:0;s:20:"property garage size";i:1;s:17:"Velikost garáže";i:2;s:10:"short text";i:3;s:1:"9";i:4;s:0:"";}i:9;a:5:{i:0;s:15:"property garage";i:1;s:8:"Garáže";i:2;s:10:"short text";i:3;s:2:"10";i:4;s:0:"";}i:10;a:5:{i:0;s:7:"zakazka";i:1;s:41:"[:cs]Číslo zakázky[:en]Order number[:]";i:2;s:7:"numeric";i:3;s:2:"11";i:4;s:0:"";}}
```

Lets say I would only want to output "zakazka" or "plochacelkem". How would I go about modifying the above code to only output that one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
 $custom_fields = get_option( 'wp_estate_custom_fields', true);    

 if(isset($custom_fields[0])){  
    for($i = 0; $i < count($custom_fields); ++$i) {

        if($custom_fields[$i][0] != 'MYNAMEHERE') continue;

        $name               =   $custom_fields[$i][0];
        $label              =   $custom_fields[$i][1];
        $type               =   $custom_fields[$i][2];
        $order              =   $custom_fields[$i][3];
        $dropdown_values    =   $custom_fields[$i][4];
        $slug               =   str_replace(' ','_',$name);

        $slug         =   wpestate_limit45(sanitize_title( $name ));
        $slug         =   sanitize_key($slug);
        $post_id      =     $post->ID;
        $show         =     1;  

        if (function_exists('icl_translate') ){
            $label     =   icl_translate('wpestate','wp_estate_property_custom_front_'.$label, $label ) ;
        }   

        if($i%2!=0){
            print '<p class="half_form half_form_last">';
        }else{
            print '<p class="half_form">';
        }
        $value=$custom_fields_array[$slug];
        wpestate_show_custom_field($show,$slug,$name,$label,$type,$order,$dropdown_values,$post_id,$value);

        break;
   }
}

?>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, Ive been stretching my brain over this for so long and probably just confused my self completely.. THANKS!